# Imageview display black image after decode in android

Tags: android, image, android-imageview, android-image

I'm working with Image steganography in android right now. For that I need to convert the image into bits array and decode it back. But when I try to convert my image back into its original shape, it showing only a black colour in my ImageView. Here is my code

```
btnEncode = (Button) findViewById(R.id.encode);
    btnEncode.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            //imgPath.setText(imageToBase64(selectedImagePath));
            ImageView imageView=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
            BitmapDrawable drawable = (BitmapDrawable) imageView.getDrawable();
            Bitmap bitmap = drawable.getBitmap();

              bytes = getBytesFromBitmap(bitmap);
              StringBuilder binary = new StringBuilder();
              for (byte b : bytes)
              {
                 int val = b;
                 for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
                 {
                    binary.append((val & 128) == 0 ? 0 : 1);
                    val <<= 1;
                 }
                 binary.append(' ');
              }

              //To save the binary in newString

            String ImageEncoded=new String(binary.toString());
            TextView imgData=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.txtResult);
            imgData.setText(ImageEncoded);
        }
    });
    btnDecode = (Button) findViewById(R.id.decode);
    btnDecode.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) 
        {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            ImageView imageView=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
            BitmapDrawable drawable = (BitmapDrawable) imageView.getDrawable();
            Bitmap bitmap = drawable.getBitmap();

              bytes = getBytesFromBitmap(bitmap);

            Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(bytes, 0, bytes.length);
            ImageView image = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView2);

            image.setImageBitmap(bmp);
        }
    });

public static byte[] getBytesFromBitmap(Bitmap bitmap)
{
    ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    bitmap.compress(CompressFormat.JPEG, 70, stream);
    return stream.toByteArray();
}
```

Comment: why this conversion is required ?

Comment: maybe that you have CompressFormat.JPEG, that would turn your transparency into black use PNG instead

Comment: Conversion required , so that i can hide a secret message in the image.. Do you think i can use any other way to do it ?

Comment: Oh, sorry for saying this , am not getting the output as expected. Now the image is not going to black , but not getting any image or nothing, Please help me with this. Is there any mistake with my code ? I just want to convert the image into its curresponding pixel values.

Answer (score 2):

Its about your converter format. Use `CompressFormat.PNG` instead of `CompressFormat.JPEG`. This caused by "JPEGs don't do transparency like PNG".

Comment: Oh, sorry for saying this , am not getting the output as expected. Now the image is not going to black , but not getting any image or nothing, Please help me with this. Is there any mistake with my code ? I just want to convert the image into its curresponding pixel values

Comment: With this change i am getting exactly same image of "R.id.imageView1" valued image at "R.id.imageView2".